# How to get count of multiple distinct columns with one column as date

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with columns as id,date,name

```
id              date                   name
 1        2019-08-01 00:00:00          abc
 1        2019-08-01 00:00:00          def
 2        2019-08-01 00:00:00          pqr
 1        2019-08-31 00:00:00          def
```

I want to get the count of id for given month.
The expected result for count of id for month 8 must be 3

```
SELECT strftime('%Y/%m/%d', date) as vdate,count(DISTINCT vdate,id) AS totalcount FROM cardtable WHERE date BETWEEN date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "', 'start of month') AND date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "','start of month','+1 month','-1 day') group by vdate
```

Basically i want to count  if id and date both are distinct.for example if there are 2 entries on date 2019-08-01 with same id than it should give count as 1,if there 3 entries on date 2019-08-01 in which 2 entries are with id 1 and 3rd entry with 2 than it should count 2 and when there are 2 entries with id 1 and on different date lets say 1 entry on 2019-08-01 with id 1 and other on 2019-08-31 with id 1 than count id for month 8 must 2.How can i modify the above query.

Comment: Try `count(DISTINCT id)` not `count(DISTINCT vdate,id)`

Comment: I tried using count(DISTINCT id) but it gives count for single date.like for above records it will give count 1 where id=1 for date=2019-08-01,than count 1 where id =2 on date 2019-08-01 and count 1 where id 1 for date=2019-08-31.but i want overall  count for month 8 i.e it should give count =3 for month 8.I want id to be distinct for particular date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery which returns the distinct values that you want to count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%Y/%m/%d', date), id 
  FROM cardtable 
  WHERE date(date) BETWEEN 
    date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "', 'start of month') 
    AND 
    date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXWBfDsQM2rdwydJ9JUgEX/0).
Results:

```
| totalcount |
| ---------- |
| 3          |
```

Comment: even this query results the same count :select count(*) as total_count from(SELECT id,strftime('%Y/%m/%d', date) as vdate FROM cardtable WHERE date BETWEEN date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "', 'start of month') AND date('" + $rootScope.mydate + "','start of month','+1 month','-1 day') GROUP BY vdate,id) total

Comment: In this case distinct and group by have the same result.